# Can't prove or disprove the existence of a limit

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I can't prove or disprove the existence of $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^3+y^2}{x^2+y}$. I have already tried several paths but still I can't prove that the limit doesn't exist. Any ideas?

Comment: Try a quadratic path. This function isn't even *defined* in a neighborhood of the origin....

Comment: You have a big problem if $y+x^2=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y=x^{4}-x^{2}$, then 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}\dfrac{x^{3}+(x^{4}-x^{2})^{2}}{x^{2}+x^{4}-x^{2}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}\dfrac{x^{8}-2x^{6}+x^{4}+x^{3}}{x^{4}}=\infty.
\end{align*}